# Flutter FireStore Query Using status

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Using the below code in my flutter app, It can display all the delivery details in my correction;

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUsersShippingStreamSnapshots(
  BuildContext context) async* {
final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
yield* Firestore.instance
    .collection('userData')
    .document(uid)
    .collection('newShipping')
    .orderBy('placedDate', descending: true)
    .snapshots();
}
```

Now, I want to display only the delivery details which has delivered status, but I'm getting an error using this code;

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getUsersShippingStreamSnapshots(
BuildContext context) async* {
final uid = await Provider.of(context).auth.getCurrentUID();
yield* Firestore.instance
    .collection('userData')
    .document(uid)
    .collection('newShipping')
    .where('status', isEqualTo: 'pending')
    .orderBy('placedDate', descending: true)
    .snapshots();
```

Help me fix this code.

Comment: So what is your error and what does the database look like?

Comment: Is tht related to indexes error?

Comment: Listen for Query(userData/jxKh6oml2rZcVKyXbWlo6InRg1H3/newShipping where status == pending order by -placedDate) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. Thats the error

Comment: Have you indexed the Entity by the proper fields?

Comment: yes, its working now thanks